# Visual Studio Express 2013 only updates UI on minimize/maximize

Tags: visual-studio

I have recently downloaded Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Desktop on my windows 7 installation. I use it for development in Unreal Engine 4. The problem I have is that when I open a project in VS I can't click on anything or at least when I do nothing happens until I minimize and the maximize the VS application. Once I do that the update shows what I clicked on. The only way I can get VS to visually update is to continue to minimize and maximize the window. Is there a way to fix this.

Clicking on menu items updates normally its only when I click on a folder in the Solution Explorer that it does not show there or on the code window.

Answer (score 0):

if you use ATI GPU, go to "configure switchable Graphic" and set "devnev.exe" to "power saving"
if you use nvidia, do same for "devnev.exe"

Comment: could you please explain how or why this helps?

Comment: that was my problem and i solved, my GPU is ATI and set "devnev.exe" to "high perfonmance" then above problem occurred. so i return it to "power saving"  then problem solved